# Specify artifact name with Intellij

Tags: jar, intellij-idea, filenames, artifact

I'd like to set the filename of the jar artifact that I build with Intellij, but as I change it, it doesn't change in the output file.

[image]

Comment: Not enough information. Make screenshot.

Comment: Might be a stupid suggestion, but did you press *Apply*?

Comment: Yes I did, it keeps to generete the file with the old name

Comment: I'm seeing the exact same thing. No matter what I do, it stays IntelliJ.jar (the name of my module/project)

Answer (score 15):

Using 2017.2.5 I am able to change the artifact name using the following steps:

1. File > Project Structure.
2. Under Project Settings > Artifacts.
3. Add a new or modify existing artifact.
4. Under Output Layout you can actually rename your JAR file to whatever you want, be sure to hit on enter to have the IDE eat up the change.

Screenshot:

[image: Changing Name of JAR File]

Comment: The key piece of information for me was to press Enter. On the Mac, pressing Return isn't enough. Press the real Enter key (on the keypad) or Fn-Return on a keyboard without a separate Enter key.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a workaround to change the filename of the JAR artifact...

1. From the Project pane, rename the module to what you'd like the JAR file to be named. The filename of the JAR is is captured from the name of the module at the time you create the artifact config.
2. Go into `Build Artifacts->Edit..` and delete the old artifact that is making the wrong JAR file name.
3. Add a new JAR Artifact. This new artifact will use whatever the name of the module is.
4. You can now go back and change the module name back.

Ugly, but works.

Note that you will likely hit [this bug](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-99596) next, so make sure you do not use the default `main/java` path to the manifest. Instead manually change it to `main/resources` - and then go vote to have both these bugs fixed!