# Java web app error during deploying the artifact

Tags: java, tomcat, apache-tomee

Facing this error when start deploying my web app from IntelliJ on the local TomEE 8 server.

```
28-Aug-2020 20:28:52.797 SEVERE [http-nio-8080-exec-8] org.apache.openejb.core.transaction.EjbTransactionUtil.handleSystemException EjbTransactionUtil.handleSystemException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Child name [/web_war_exploded] is not unique
    org.apache.openejb.OpenEJBRuntimeException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Child name [/web_war_exploded] is not unique
        at org.apache.tomee.catalina.deployment.TomcatWebappDeployer.deploy(TomcatWebappDeployer.java:58)
        at org.apache.openejb.assembler.DeployerEjb.deploy(DeployerEjb.java:177)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
        at org.apache.openejb.core.interceptor.ReflectionInvocationContext$Invocation.invoke(ReflectionInvocationContext.java:205)
        at org.apache.openejb.core.interceptor.ReflectionInvocationContext.proceed(ReflectionInvocationContext.java:186)
        at org.apache.openejb.security.internal.InternalSecurityInterceptor.invoke(InternalSecurityInterceptor.java:35)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
        at org.apache.openejb.core.interceptor.ReflectionInvocationContext$Invocation.invoke(ReflectionInvocationContext.java:205)
        at org.apache.openejb.core.interceptor.ReflectionInvocationContext.proceed(ReflectionInvocationContext.java:186)
        at org.apache.openejb.monitoring.StatsInterceptor.record(StatsInterceptor.java:191)
        at org.apache.openejb.monitoring.StatsInterceptor.invoke(StatsInterceptor.java:102)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
        at org.apache.openejb.core.interceptor.ReflectionInvocationContext$Invocation.invoke(ReflectionInvocationContext.java:205)
        at org.apache.openejb.core.interceptor.ReflectionInvocationContext.proceed(ReflectionInvocationContext.java:186)
        at org.apache.openejb.core.interceptor.InterceptorStack.invoke(InterceptorStack.java:85)
        at org.apache.openejb.core.singleton.SingletonContainer._invoke(SingletonContainer.java:272)
        at org.apache.openejb.core.singleton.SingletonContainer.invoke(SingletonContainer.java:221)
        at org.apache.openejb.server.ejbd.EjbRequestHandler.doEjbObject_BUSINESS_METHOD(EjbRequestHandler.java:371)
        at org.apache.openejb.server.ejbd.EjbRequestHandler.processRequest(EjbRequestHandler.java:182)
        at org.apache.openejb.server.ejbd.EjbDaemon.processEjbRequest(EjbDaemon.java:360)
        at org.apache.openejb.server.ejbd.EjbDaemon.service(EjbDaemon.java:247)
        at org.apache.openejb.server.ejbd.EjbServer.service(EjbServer.java:104)
        at org.apache.openejb.server.httpd.ServerServlet.service(ServerServlet.java:60)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:733)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
        at org.apache.tomee.catalina.OpenEJBValve.invoke(OpenEJBValve.java:45)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
        at org.apache.tomee.catalina.OpenEJBSecurityListener$RequestCapturer.invoke(OpenEJBSecurityListener.java:97)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:690)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:373)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1589)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
    Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Child name [/web_war_exploded] is not unique
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:703)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:690)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:705)
        at org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomcatWebAppBuilder.deployWar(TomcatWebAppBuilder.java:658)
        at org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomcatWebAppBuilder.deployWebApps(TomcatWebAppBuilder.java:598)
        at org.apache.tomee.catalina.deployment.TomcatWebappDeployer.deploy(TomcatWebappDeployer.java:47)
        ... 52 more

**[2020-08-28 08:28:52,845] Artifact web:war exploded: Error during artifact deployment. See server log for details.**
[2020-08-28 08:28:52,845] Artifact web:war exploded: javax.ejb.EJBException: The bean encountered a non-application exception; nested exception is: 
    org.apache.openejb.OpenEJBRuntimeException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Child name [/web_war_exploded] is not unique
```

Answer (score 1):

```
org.apache.openejb.OpenEJBRuntimeException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Child name [/web_war_exploded] is not unique
```

means, that the name of one web application, conflicts with another one.

You can either try to use some different name, or remove conflicting `.war` file (and its respective exploded folder which is found in `/webapps`) if you no longer need it.

How to rename the project packaging?

There are two ways in your case:

1. If you have a Maven project, you can add this snippet in the pom.xml:

   ```
   <build>
       <finalName>your_war_name</finalName>
       ...
   </build>
   ```
2. If you are deploying the application right from the IntelliJ (in the embedded configured TomEE server), you can configure the `war` name as [explained here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21986831/specify-artifact-name-with-intellij).

Comment: I do not have application with this name!

Comment: Neither war nor folder? does this exception still happen?

Comment: Maybe you can try answers from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27376826/java-lang-illegalargumentexception-addchild-child-name-is-not-unique)?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Child name [/web_war_exploded] is not unique. InteliJ is not deleting previous deployment. go to your tomcat webapp directory and remove web_war_exploded folder. Or you could rename your artifact.